# CodeIgniter - calling method from a variable

Tags: codeigniter

Let's keep it simple.
We have this:

```
public function db($method)
    {   
        $this->$method.'()';
    }
```

I'am sure this is pretty self explanatory. Basically I want all my methods to be called trough this method 'db', but this is the error:

> Message: Undefined property: site::$db

Ehm...

I guess I could write all the possible cases by hand, but is it really necessary??

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried `call_user_func($function);`
Or

```
$this->$function()
```

Or

```
$this->{$function}()
```